# Python Pandas - how to add a total row to sum certain columns and take the average for others

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that is working as intended

```
df['FPYear'] = df['First_Purchase_Date'].dt.year
# Table2 = df.loc[df.Date.between('2018-11-22','2018-11-30')].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() #with date filters for table
Table2 = df.loc[df.Date.between('2018-11-22','2018-11-30') & (df['Region'] == 'Canada')].groupby(df['FPYear'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'revenue']].sum() #with date filters for table
Table2['TotalCusts'] = Table2['New Customer'] + Table2['Existing Customer']
Table2['Cohort Size'] = Table['New Customer']

Table2['Repeat Rate'] = Table2['Existing Customer']/Table2['TotalCusts']
Table2['NewCust Rate'] = Table2['New Customer']/Table2['TotalCusts']
Table2['PCT of Total Yr'] = Table2['TotalCusts']/Table['New Customer']
Table2.loc['Total'] = Table2.sum(axis = 0) this code totals all columns.  #the below calcs totals for some and average for others

cols = ["Repeat Rate", "NewCust Rate"]
diff_cols = Table2.columns.difference(cols)
Table2.loc['Total'] = Table2[diff_cols].sum().append(Table2[cols].mean())
```

Instead of calculating the means for "Repeat Rate" and "NewCust Rate" as the code is doing now, how can I formulas so that the total rows for those columsn are using the following formulas instead:

Repeat Rate = Table['Existing Customer']/Table2['TotalCusts']
NewCust Rate = Table['New Customer']/Table2['TotalCusts']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all columns without specifying in list for `sum` and columns in list for `mean` with [`Series.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) for join together:

```
cols = ["Repeat Rate", "NewCust Rate"]
diff_cols = Table2.columns.difference(cols)
Table2.loc['Total'] = Table2[diff_cols].sum().append(Table2[cols].mean())
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the "difference" function do? Do you have documentation where I can read up further on that?

Comment: Also, what if I didn't want to take the average of the but wanted to divide the total of each column (repeat and new) by the total customers column?  Can I just modify the code for the mean of the columns or do I have to define two separate columns for each calc.  Thanks.

Comment: The proposed solution gave me the average for Repeat and New Cust rate but it gives a value of 'nan' for all other columns.  what if I want to sum all other columns and average 'repeat' and new cust'

Comment: @wolfblitza - can you test now?

Comment: Awesome. it looks like it works. Thanks Jezrael!
what exactly is the difference function?